# Dapper Multiple Results From single query

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

Hi i am trying to get to grips with Dapper.

My situation is i want to pull two values from a query into two separate strings. Im not sure if i am going about this in the correct way, but this is what i am doing:

```
string sql = @"Select type, name 
              FROM ZipData 
              WHERE Zip = @zip";

using (var multi = conn.QueryMultiple(sql, new { zip = zip }))
{
   string result = multi.Read<string>().SingleOrDefault();         
}
```

And i am getting Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'GridReader'. when trying to read the second string.The thing is it gets the first value correctly and has both the fields in in the reader i am trying to get. Im sure im misusing the api.

What am i doing wrong here? Ive googled but can find a specific example.

Comment: Your two values represent two columns in your SELECT statement?  Or two *rows* in two *separate* SELECT statements?   (better yet, just show us your SQL)

Comment: Yeh they are both there, i will add my SQL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are mis-using `QueryMultiple`.  That is defined for compound SQL statements that return *multiple* result sets.   Something like:

```
SELECT Foo FROM MyTable;
SELECT Bar FROM MyOtherTable;
```

On the other hand, you are trying to get two different *columns* from a *single* result set, so you should just use the normal `Query` method:

```
var result = conn.Query(sql, new { zip = zip }).Single();
var type = result.type;
var name = result.name;
```

`Query` returns an enumerable (because generally a query can return multiple rows).  It appears that you only want one row, however, so we invoke `.Single` at the end to just get that row.  From there, the return type is `dynamic` so you can simply refer to the properies implied by the columns in your `SELECT` statement: `type` and `name`.

Comment: i guessed i was misusing it. Thankyou for your quick answer :) The dynamic return type is cool.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to use the `dynamic` keyword when defining `result`. Such as `dynamic result = conn.Query(sql, new { zip = zip }).Single();`

Comment: @webworm no, the [signature of the method](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L615) is `public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Query(...)`, so each row is already declared as `dynamic`.